# jQuery Define a Global Variable for an element that does not yet exist in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm working on a page where user can create a form by clicking to insert  fields. Initially no input elements exist on the page. User clicks to created them. I'm trying to create Global variables to reference those input fields so i can later make use of this, but since input fields do not initially exist in DOM, the global variable is giving undefined. Anyway way around this. I want the variables to be global, because i want to make use of them in other functions.

Ex:

```
var $selected = $('#form').find('.selected input').val(); //Global variable outside the function. Since this doesn't initially exist in DOM, it's giving undefined.
```

Comment: than go for document.ready method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the same variables everywhere. However, the catch being that since the DOM is initially empty, you have to populate those variables when a user creates these objects.

```
var $selected;
```

Say when the user clicked a button to insert an input element. The `$selected` variable has to be updated at this time.

```
function addTextInput() {
    var input = $('<input type="text" value="awesome" />');
    $("form .selected").append(input);

    // the global variable is being updated now.
    $selected = $('#form .selected input').val();
}
```

Comment: +1, but to keep it DRY, I'd suggest a `function reselectInputs() { $selected = $('#form .selected input').val(); };` - conceivably, changes like these might happen in several places in code.

Comment: @Amadan - it may be best to not reply on global variables, but instead use functions for everything, including getting the value of an input field.

Comment: I originally did suggest so in my answer, but OP wanted to cache the results. Your answer is the closest to his wishes.

Comment: What happens when the user deletes the field, I have about 15 variables. No sure if there's a better solution to this.

Comment: If you hold on to a reference of the field (`$selected`), then it will not get deleted, even if a user removes it from the DOM. 15 global variables sounds too much to manage, so I'd suggest you consider alternate solutions. You can post the bigger picture problem as a new question on SO, and get more ideas from the community.

Answer (score 1):

If the collection of the INPUTs changes, why do you want it to be statically captured in a variable? Just select them each time you need them.

Comment: I have many uses for this. I reference the global variables by class. Each input type have a class. The reason for the global variable is so i can cache the variables instead of having to recreate an object everytime.

Comment: Then the approach that I suggest is that you do actually treat it as cache: whenever you do anything that could change the collection, reselect it, as @Anurag suggests.